# Possible to verify a contract address without having access to the creator address?

Tags: solidity, contract-deployment

My previous question relates to this linked question where a user answered by saying he verified the contract address on behalf of the creator without really having access to it.

[Publish and verify the source contract code in Ethscan. I tried it but it keeps failing. Can anyone help me?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/74785/publish-and-verify-the-source-contract-code-in-ethscan-i-tried-it-but-it-keeps/151981?noredirect=1#comment169470_151981)

Any ideas or leads on how this was done is be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It's only verified on the specific block explorer. It is up the the explorer to decide if and how to gate the process. Most don't.

I have seen many examples where people have used that to include adverts at the top of the verified source, since comments are not considered in the compilation.

Example: [image]
https://snowtrace.io/address/0x1b02da8cb0d097eb8d57a175b88c7d8b47997506#contracts